# Bootstrap collapse doesn't add .collapsed when using class selector

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.4.  I have a panel with a heading and footer, and a glyphicon to indicate the open/closed state of the panel.

If I use the id of the panel body as the selector for collapse then Bootstrap correctly applies the `.collapsed` class to the heading and the glyphicon changes.  However, I want to also collapse the footer so I changed to using a class selector for collapse.  The good news is the footer now also collapses; the bad news is that `.collapsed` is no longer applied to the heading and thus the glyphicon doesn't change.

#### CSS

```css
.collapsible {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.panel-heading.collapsible:after {
    font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
    content:"\e114";
    float: right;
    color: darkslategary;
}
.panel-heading.collapsible.collapsed:after {
    content:"\e080";
}
```

#### HTML

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div id="theHeader2" class="panel-heading collapsible" data-target=".shrinkme" data-toggle="collapse">Collapse</div>
  <div id="theBody2" class="panel-body shrinkme collapse in">
        nim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life
  </div>
  <div id="theFooter2" class="panel-footer shrinkme collapse in">
    <button class="btn btn-default">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-deciduous"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3xvdsy2/) demonstrating both selectors

Am I doing something that's keeping `.collapsed` from being applied?  How can I collapse the body and footer when the heading is clicked?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here's the answer:

- Make the footer panel a child of the body panel.
- Use class `panel-collapse` on the body panel instead of `panel`

The first item is the key; the second one is for proper styling. I stumbled upon the solution by reading [this issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/issues/113).

#### Here is the revised [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3xvdsy2/2/) with the updated HTML.

#### Updated HTML

```html
<div class="panel">
    <div id="theHeader" class="panel-heading collapsible" data-target="#theBody" data-toggle="collapse">Collapse using id as the selector</div>
    <div id="theBody" class="panel-collapse collapse in">nim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life.
        <div id="theFooter" class="panel-footer collapse in">
            <button class="btn btn-default"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-grain"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

bootstrap only adds the class to there is #id or href and not class.

according to the docs you are suppose to target the collapse using two options

```
   data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample"
```

or

```
    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="theBody2"
```

this way you do not have to add a `cursor:pointer` manually as well

Comment: It's becoming a pattern to find "the real right answer" after the "official right answer". Thanks a lot.

Comment: Jeez, thanks dude, like really! (and caruso_g is right)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the there is an workaround, the data-target works with class selector but really doesn't change the parent class.

On the parent element you can handle onClick event, like:

```
onClick="(e) => { e.currentTarget.classList.contains("collaspsed") ? e.currentTarget.classList.remove("collaspsed") : e.currentTarget.classList.add("collaspsed"); }"
```